# Python email send cc instead of bcc

Tags: python, email, amazon-ses, cc, bcc

We have written python code that sends emails.
Bcc is an array of 2 emails and there is no cc.
Even though there is no CC, the BCC emails are added as CC.

Here is the code:

```
bcc = "x, y"
response = self.connection.send_email(
    source = sender_mail,
    subject = subject,
    body = None,
    to_addresses = to,
    cc_addresses=None,
    bcc_addresses=bcc,
    format='html',
    reply_addresses = None,
    return_path = None,
    text_body=None,
    html_body=html
)
```

Any idea how we can solve this?

Comment: `bcc = "x, y"` is not an array of two emails, it is a string. It should be something like `bcc = ['x@example.com', 'y@example.com']`.

Comment: That right. It was written correctly in the code though. Found what the problem is.
We figured out the problem. We use nohup on the email sending process. So when we restarted it the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
bcc = "x, y"
```

is **not** an array. Rather go for:

```
bcc = [x, y]
```

Comment: That right. It was written correctly in the code though. Found what the problem is.